# MongoDB - Find documents which contain an element in an array which has a property of null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple query in mongodb.

I have a `job` collection that has objects like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5995c1fc3c2a353a782ee51b"),
    "stages" : [
            {
                "start" : ISODate("2017-02-02T22:06:26Z"),
                "end" : ISODate("2017-02-03T22:06:26Z"),
                "name" : "stage_one"
            },
            {
                "start" : ISODate("2017-02-03T22:06:26Z"),
                "end" : ISODate("2017-02-07T20:34:01Z"),
                "name" : "stage_two"
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to get a job whose second stage does not have an end time, i.e. `end` is null or not defined.

According to the mongo docs on [querying for null](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#equality-filter) and [querying an array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#use-the-array-index-to-query-for-a-field-in-the-embedded-document), it would seem the correct query should be:

```
db.job.findOne({'stages.1.end': null})
```

However, running that query returns me the job above which *does* have a non-null end date. In fact, if I run the query with `count` instead of `findOne`, I see that all jobs are returned - no filtering is done at all.

For completeness, here is the output from an example on a fresh mongo instance:

[image: Example]

So in this example, I would expect `db.job.findOne({'stages.1.end': null})` to return nothing since there is only one document and its second stage has a non-null end date.

This feels like the sort of issue where it's just me being an idiot and if so, I apologise profusely.

Thanks in advance for your help and let me know if you need any more details!

**EDIT:**

After some more experimentation, I think I can achieve what I want with the following:

```
db.job.find({$or: [{'stages.1.end': { $type: 10 }}, {'stages.1.end': {$exists: false}}]})
```

While this gets the job done, it doesn't feel like the simplest way and I still don't understand why the original query doesn't work. If anyone could shed some light on this it'd be much appreciated.